# problem with implenting __len__ with sqlalchemy func.count getting some kind of recursion error

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

the code - supposed to implent the **len** magic method with the following code:

```
    def __len__(self):

    from sqlalchemy import func
    self.len = session.query(func.count(Question.id)).scalar()
    return int(self.len)

def __repr__(self):

    self.repr = "traffic theory question, current number of questions:{0}".format(self.__len__)
    return self.repr
```

what I get (the 3 upper lines keep on repeating in a long list and then terminate with the following line):

```
  File "C:\Python27\dir\file.py", line 129, in __repr__
    self.repr = "traffic theory question, current number of questions:{0}".format(self.__len__)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

I should stress I'm getting this error only when calling the **repr** class method but when I call len(q) (q is the class instance i'm working with) I get the right answer!

any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `format` an instance method, `self.__len__`, not the length returned by that instance method.

When you try to `format(self.__len__)`, it calls `repr` on the instance referred to by `self`, creating the recursion.

You need to use `format` on `self.__len__()` (or `len(self)` or `self.len`).

Comment: ye, figured it out just now should have used .len. thanks anyway